# Maximizing dy/dx in a Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP

$$ y' = f(t,y) = t^2 + y^2$$

$$y(0) = 0$$

Let R be the Rectangle defined as $$t\in[-1/2,1/2]$$ $$y\in[-1/7,1/7]$$

Find Max f(t,y) where t,y belong to R and find the Lipschitz Constant defined as $$ |f(t,y1)-f(t,y2)|<=L|y1-y2|$$

Could someone point me in the right direction here? My Calculus is a bit rusty so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I see you're a new user. Please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

To get a Lipschitz constant note that

$$|f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2)|=|y_1^2-y_2^2|=|y_1+y_2||y_1-y_2|.$$

To get the maximum of $f$ note that $x\to x^2$ is increasing in $[0,L].$

Comment: Do you want to have the maximum of $f$ on the rectangle or the maximum of $f$ along the solution of the IPV?

Comment: Maximum of f(t,y) where t,y can take on values on the Rectangle. Here's my thought process till now. Since y' = f(t,y) >= 0 for all t, this implies that y is an increasing function of t. Hence, the maximum will be achieved by picking the largest value of t on the interval given. I also forgot to mention this but I'm given the value of y(1/2) in the question so I suppose that's enough to answer the maximum question right since the end point of my interval is 1/2.                                      Still lost on Lipschitz though.

Comment: If you try to get the maximum value on the rectangle it is achieved at $(\pm1/2,\pm1/7).$ If it is along the trajectory then it is achieved at $(\pm 1/2, y(\pm1/2)).$ Since you know the value of $y(\pm1/2)$ you can get the solution.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I also understood your Lipschitz hint. I'm just wondering about one last thing though. For |y1+y2| would I use the upper bound of the Rectangle which would make L = 2/7 or would I evaluate it as y(1/2) + y(1/2)

Comment: On the rectangle the best Lipschitz constant is $2/7.$ If you evaluate along the trajectory, you can't consider $|y(1/2)+y(-1/2)|$ because (you should need to know the values for any $t$) it doesn't have to be the best bound. So, I will use $2/7.$

Comment: @user145003 Please add the information that $y(1/2)$ is given to the question. And since you're a registered member, please consider up voting this answer which clearly helped you.